# how to change background color image using php gd

Tags: php, gd

I have created a website http://www.example.com and i want to change color of its widget using [PHP GD](http://php.net/book.image).

lets widget URL is `www.example.com/widget.gif`

When I pass hexadecimal value to this URL it should change colour like

```
www.example.com/widget.gif?bg=#CC66CC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code

Give your color code in gd function IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE

```
    $imgname = "source.png";           
    $im = imagecreatefrompng ($imgname);              
    if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 137, 113, 79))               
    {
         echo 'Image successfully shaded green.';                

         imagepng($im, 'result.png');             
         imagedestroy($im);                     
    }                  
   else               
   {
        echo 'Green shading failed.';
   }
```